# Populate ACF Checkboxes with Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to populate a checkbox ACF field with the various post types of a WP site. This is for a plugin, so the post types will vary based on the location of install.

By default, the plugin uses pages and posts as it's post types, but need to give user option to use checkboxes to select other CPT's on the site. How can I populate the checkbox field with the list of all CPT's on a site. Here is my current section of PHP code to load the field within the plugin

```
array (
    'key' => 'field_56e6d87b6c7be',
    'label' => 'Add to Custom Post Types',
    'name' => 'fb_pixel_cpt_select',
    'type' => 'checkbox',
    'instructions' => 'Select which Custom Post Types you would like to use.',
    'required' => 0,
    'conditional_logic' => 0,
    'wrapper' => array (
        'width' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'id' => '',
    ),
    'choices' => array (
    ),
    'default_value' => array (
    ),
    'layout' => 'vertical',
    'toggle' => 0,
),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the ACF load field function here to auto populate your field. See more here: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acfload_field/

Then, using the Wordpress get_post_types call (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) you could retrieve those values and populate your field like this.

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=fb_pixel_cpt_select', 'acf_load_post_types');

function acf_load_post_types($field)
{
    foreach ( get_post_types( '', 'names' ) as $post_type ) {
       $field['choices'][$post_type] = $post_type;
    }

    // return the field
    return $field;
}
```

Make sure that your field is already created before you try to populate it though.

Comment: Thanks @andrew! This is fantastic! How would I add in arguments for the following. Ideally I want to only display public CPT that are not the builtin ones `$args = array( 'public' => true, '_builtin' => false );`

Comment: Keith, what you can use is the post_type parameter in WP Query. See the docs here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters You can pass in a string or an array for the type so you can retrieve items from multiple post types

Answer (score 4):

This will create a select field for your ACF block or whatever that has all the post types except those that don't have a nav menu (such as the attachment post type).

```
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=select_post_type', 'yourprefix_acf_load_post_types');
/*
 *  Load Select Field `select_post_type` populated with the value and labels of the singular 
 *  name of all public post types
 */
function yourprefix_acf_load_post_types( $field ) {

    $choices = get_post_types( array( 'show_in_nav_menus' => true ), 'objects' );

    foreach ( $choices as $post_type ) :
        $field['choices'][$post_type->name] = $post_type->labels->singular_name;
    endforeach;
    return $field;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer was really useful because it's a clever trick to return a combination of intentionally created post types and default post types and none of the internally used ones, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do this (choose from list of post types) I would be creating a list of posts based on post-type to feed into WP Query. So I use a select field in ACF, and add the post type names into the select options when creating the field, e.g.

```
posts : Posts
```

which I then use in the arguments for the WP Query, like so:

```
$theselectfield = get_field('theselectfield');
```

Then use it in the argument of the query:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => $theselectfield,
'some_other' => 'argument',
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).